# Website width. centering content in a wrap

Tags: css, wrapper, center, fluid

There has been so many different answers to this and I'm having a hard time figuring out what I should be practicing. Currently I am using a script to center my page. I got it from someone on this site, but I don't know enough javascript to understand it.

This is the code im using

```
    $( document ).ready( function(){
setMaxWidth();

function setMaxWidth() {
$( ".page_wrap" ).css( "maxWidth", ( $( window ).width() * 0.7 | 0 ) + "px" );
}

});
```

At first I thought this worked well, but after zooming out and refreshing, it adapts and stretches out everything. This isn't a huge problem, but I've noticed that professional sites are using this method as their sites don't break after doing the same thing.

For a div wrap and centering content, must I use a 960px width? I don't like using fixed widths.

if you notice on this site: http://themetrust.com/demos/hero/

they're not using media queries to make it responsive. As you zoom in and out it adapts nicely. This is what I'm aiming for with me site.

Comment: `em's` are only relatively fixed and media queries are part of the future web, don't shy away from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common tecnique to horizontally center elements is to give an explicit width to the contained element (must be a block element) and use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

This is what the website you linked is using as well. Fixed width are ok if used consciously, better if they adapt to different screensizes through media queries.

Comment: so you're saying I should stick with the 960px wrap and use media queries to change instead going toward the fluid design route where things change on resize?

Comment: 960px could be for example the wrap width when you target 1024px screens. The explicit size is just needed to center the div. Fluid layouts are a bit different, I would say (they react to the slightest resize). It really depends on the design you want to achieve.

Comment: Can't upvote yet, but I gave you best answer. I solved my problem by giving my page wrap a min width and max width. seems to have worked nicely. things adapt on resize without media queries and nothing breaks. still going to use media queries, but I like the fluid design.

Answer (score 0):

Use frameworks instead of placing each elements by hand and with jquery! Saves time, saves effort, causes less errors. Try [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)